# Perfoming setTImeout action before going to next loop iteration

Tags: javascript, settimeout, wait

I am trying to repeat the pattern in the memory game simon before adding another step in the sequence, but I think the loop is being iterated through so quickly that every number in the sequence is calling setTimeout(function, 1000) at essentially the same time and then they are played simultaneously rather than one after another. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
function playPattern(){
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<pattern.length; i++){
        var currentNum = pattern[i];
        if(currentNum === 0){
            var greenNoise = new Audio("greenNoise.mp3");
            greenNoise.play();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#71FF4A";
            ctx.fillRect(10, 30, w/2-10, h/3);
            setTimeout(drawGameBoard, 1000);
        } else if (currentNum === 1){
            var redNoise = new Audio("redNoise.mp3");
            redNoise.play();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#F73B3E";
            ctx.fillRect(w/2, 30, w/2-10, h/3);
            setTimeout(drawGameBoard, 1000);    
        } else if (currentNum === 2){
            var yellowNoise = new Audio("yellowNoise.mp3");
            yellowNoise.play();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF269";
            ctx.fillRect(10, h/3+30, w/2-10, h/3);          
            setTimeout(drawGameBoard, 1000);
        } else { //currentNum === 3
            var blueNoise = new Audio("blueNoise.mp3");
            blueNoise.play();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#58ACF5";
            ctx.fillRect(w/2, h/3+30, w/2-10, h/3);         
            setTimeout(drawGameBoard, 1000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(increasePattern, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Your analysis is correct. You can call *setTimeout* once have each iteration call the next one when it's finished, or you can multiply the lag by the increment in the *setTimeout* call. But having a whole bunch queued may not suit.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, all the functions are being queued for the same interval. You can fix that by multiplying the interval by the iteration count, e.g.

```
setTimeout(increasePattern, 1000 * i);
```

But that will queue a bunch of functions to run in a sequence. Consider instead having the function call itself at the selected interval until some condition is met, e.g.

```js
// This function does all the setup
function doStuff(num) {

  // Keep limit in a closure
  var limit = num;

  // This function does the work
  function realStuff() {

    // While limit is greater than zero, do stuff...
    if (limit) {

      // Decrement limit
      --limit;
      
      // Trivial thing to do
      console.log(limit);

      // Call itself again
      setTimeout(realStuff, 1000);
    }
  }

  // Initiate the first time
  realStuff();
}

doStuff(10);
```

You can also adjust the timeout on each call to see if you want it a bit sooner or later to try and hit a regular time interval to a higher accuracy over a long period. And you can cancel the sequence by just not calling the next *setTimeout*, or by making the interval identifier available outside the function so it can be cancelled by a call to *clearTimeout*.